# ML Algorithm for Parking floor traffic congestion

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

I'm trying to create an ML Algorithm to predict traffic congestion at a particular floor at a particular time. I'm New to Machine learning. Currently in learning mode. Trying to start with some classification algorithm later to time series.

Generated one data-set. Which contains 4 floors.

I'm little bit confused on searching internet for reference. Anyone have some idea where i need to start. Its great if i get some similar reference too.

Data-set looks like following

```
'Floor Number'  'Slot Number'  Date               'Sensor Data'
3               95             1-jan-2000 1:5:39  1
```

Where sensor data indicate whether the vehicle is parked (`1`) or left (`0`)

Comment: How are you defining 'congested'?

Comment: Maximum number of movement happening area . with the sensor data.